# How to check whether field value is an instance of DateTime or even Date

Tags: datetime, cakephp, format, instanceof, cakephp-3.x

I have a date of birth field whoes value when printed as $entity->date_of_birth, is like this:

```
object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {

    'time' => '1948-02-18T00:00:00+00:00',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'fixedNowTime' => false

}
```

I want to place date format checks in my view files with help of a helper functions so that whenever a field has **Cake\I18n\FrozenDate** or even **DateTime** instance I can run a date format and match function. I tried to place a check as

```
$entity->date_of_birth instanceof Cake\I18n\FrozenDate
```

but it doesn't work. What is the ideal way to check for the instance of datetime in CakePHP. I also need this check to be put in the beforeSave call so I can format newly entered date strings to SQL format before saving it.

Comment: I guess you are just missing a `\ `. It works with `instanceof \Cake\I18n\FrozenDate `

Comment: @arilia is right, but I wonder why you have these issues at all. How is date string data getting into your entities in the first place, such that you need to take these exceptional steps? Seems like it should be handled at the source instead of everywhere that it might end up being used.